# Não consigo achar o model gerado pelo artisan

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, postgresql, laravel-eloquent

Eu usei o comando `php artisan make:model Exemplo` e não consegui achar onde ele salvou esse model gerado para que eu pudesse alterar ele. Olhei na pasta app/html e não achei nada.

A minha db já ta pronta, então eu não preciso usar o migrate, mas preciso do modelo pra usar o query builder pelo que entendi.

Comment: procure dentro da pasta `app`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Laravel por padrão salva as `models` criadas através do `Artisan` no diretório `app/`, Provavelmente esteja lá, não faria sentido mesmo estar no diretório que tu estás procurando, pois uma Model não possui relação alguma com arquivos `HTML`.

Comment: Olha só, até concordo em partes na sua resposta, mas, se eu quiser colocar a criação dentro da pasta `app/html` eu posso, nada impede e não estaria errado, talvez um melhor local seria `app/Models`, tendo correlação pelo nome e um namespace `App/Models` teria um padrão melhor. Parabéns pela resposta

Comment: Claro que podes colocar onde quiseres.  Mas na minha opinião não faria muito sentido. Também sou a favor de criar uma estrutura app/Models como tu citou.

Comment: Ok, só foi mesmo uma observação.

Answer (score 0):

como eu faço para trocar o caminho para criar em App/Models eu já troquei no composer e no auth que uso autenticaç;ao mais no artisan make:model continua criando na app